# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'

Tags: python, django, formwizard

I have got following django code for Formwizard in python. First there are two forms:

```
 class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
      FirstName = forms.CharField(max_length=500)
      LastName = forms.CharField(max_length=500)

 class SurveyForm(forms.Form):
      def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(SurveyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
       for question in choiceValue:
                self.fields[question] =  forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES,widget=RadioSelect())

class ContactWizard(FormWizard):
choiceValue = []

def get_template(self,step): 
    if step == 0:
        return 'wizard0.html'
    if step == 1:
        return 'wizard1.html'

def process_step(self, request, form, step):
    if (step == 0):      
        fullName=""      
        if request.method== 'POST':               
            if form.is_valid():  
                FirstName = form.cleaned_data['FirstName']
                LastName = form.cleaned_data['LastName']
                FirstNameU=FirstName.capitalize()
                LastNameU=LastName.capitalize()
                fullName=FirstNameU+" "+LastNameU
                personURIfn=GraphR.triples((None,FOAF_NS['givenName'],Literal(FirstNameU)))
                personURIln=GraphR.triples((None,FOAF_NS['familyName'],Literal(LastNameU)))          
                for purifn in personURIfn:
                    purifnStr='%s' %purifn[0]
                    for puriln in personURIln:     
                        purilnStr='%s' %puriln[0]
                        if purifnStr == purilnStr:               
                            personURI=purifnStr
                            friendKnows=GraphR.triples((URIRef(purifnStr),FOAF_NS['knows'],None))
                            for fk in friendKnows: #and scn1 not in epuriList1:            
                                fkStr='%s' %fk[2]
                                choiceValue.append(fkStr)
                return render_to_response('wizard1.html', RequestContext(request))


def done(self, request, form_list):
    print 'run'
```

I am not getting why it is giving error mentioned in the Title. Moreover Google is also not providing any specific help. Could anyone of you please guess the cause of it. I suspect something wrong happening in Done method but not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: I have added step 1, elif (step == 1):  
            if request.method== 'POST':
                print 'Step1 is', step , but in Done I have to add data in the database from choicefields. How can I proceed? Please guide.

Comment: It is still giving the same error by the way. 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'set_cookie'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Think about what happens in `process_step` if if's not step 0, or if it's a GET rather than a POST, or if the form is not valid. What is returned in those cases?